# SSD behaves as if it is "read-only" but softwares that have been used "think" the opposite

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, diskpart, issue-tracking

**Wierd behaviour of ssd,** not letting me to format it or do anything else except of reading/copying files, **as if it is "read-only" but it isn't read-only** *(based on what diskpart says)*... **for example when:**

- *"DISKPART> DETAIL Disk"* it **outputs** *"... Read-only  : No".*
- *"DISKPART> CLEAN"* **says** *["DiskPart succeeded in cleaning disk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAC26.jpg)*, **then** i [re-initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZk5d.jpg) <sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53Ij.jpg)</sup> it and all [files reapear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUTXZ.jpg)!
- [passing files on the drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBlcl.jpg) and **then** remounting it, [those files
  disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LtS7.jpg) *(like they where never created)*.

**Seems to me like.. it's failing? ..any idea?**
[Here another screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YGD1.jpg)

<sup><sub>the SSD that i am using is the *"Verbatium Vi550 S3"*, pretty **new** / i've only used it for 3-5 months</sub></sup>

Comment: Seems like this SSD is dead.

Comment: Formatting tip: when everything is emphasized, it's like nothing is emphasized, except harder to read.

Comment: @harrymc then why i am able to read and copy files out of it? and what could cause it to die so "young"?

Comment: It seems as if the disk has problems with writing. There is no age for disks, this is only a matter of luck. All disk numbers are only statistical in nature, and there are exceptions either way.

Comment: @harrymc do you have any idea of any software that i could use to make sure it's not anything else? or just to makes sure that it is indeed dead?

Comment: Your images are inaccessible, you should edit your question, and use the Image icon to upload your files.

Comment: @Ramhound *"You are not allowed to embed images... as soon as you earn 10 rep.."* ... What do you mean by inaccessible?

Comment: @GiorgosXou - I mean 404

Comment: Look at the SMART data of the disk. When a disk has too many bad sectors it may become read-only, which is possibly what happened here.

Comment: @harrymc i did *"wmic diskdrive get model, status"* and *"Status"* was *"OK"

Comment: Look at the SMART data.

Comment: @harrymc [SATAFIRM S11](https://image.prntscr.com/image/iciGLs2WQFigX8svb_6muQ.png) ??!?

Comment: I get "403 Forbidden". Please put your images on [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/).

Comment: @harrymc **Done** here the [SATAFIRM S11 screenshot too](https://imgur.com/3a9toRT)

Comment: **i've also tried to download & use the ["Vi550 Verbatim SSD Utility"](https://www.verbatim.com/prod/ssd/vi550-sata-iii-2.5-internal-ssds/128gb-vi550-sata-iii-2.5-internal-ssd-sku-49350/) but i had no luck with it**

Comment: The "Bad Block Count" is 67. This is not serious for an old disk, but in disquieting in a new disk. For the moment the disk seems in good health, but you should keep an eye on it. Did you test if the disk is read-only? Is it still under warranty?

Comment: @harrymc as i've said on the post, **it behaves as if it is read-only but diskpart says it's not**... **it is indeed under warranty but** the guy who gave it to me, can't find the receipt to return it *(meanwhile i guess that he is searching)*.... **so** is it for *"Bad Block Count"* that i can't write on it?

Comment: "Bad Block Count" of 67 is usually nothing, since the disk should have thousands of spare ones. These bad blocks were correctly recovered and remapped to spare good blocks, since you didn't have any unrecoverable errors. I suggest returning the disk (unless you find a read-only switch on it that you can turn off). And next time keep the receipt yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with your SSD. Have you tried using [gparted](https://gparted.org/)?

1. Create a new partition table (**this will destroy all the data!**).
2. Create and resize (if needed) the partition.

EDIT: try this using terminal (note that you will need `sudo` for most of these commands):

1. `sudo umount /dev/sdb`
2. `parted /dev/sdb -- mklabel msdos`.
3. `parted /dev/sdb -- mkpart primary 1MiB -8GiB`
4. `mkfs.ext4 -L newpart /dev/sdb1`

**!!PLEASE REMEMBER THAT THIS WILL ERASE ANY CONTENT ON THE DRIVE!!**

Comment: When i run *"GParted"* with the SSD mounted i get an error of *["Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdb"](https://imgur.com/yZ3uRet)*, when i try to Create partition table i get [this error](https://imgur.com/nLLbTsa) and then again the ["Invalid.."](https://imgur.com/0StlnH2) and **files still there nothing changed**

Comment: Can you post the partition table? `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` (looks like `sdb` in your case). Also, is the disk in `RAID`?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/Hq5dY6K) .. How do i know if it is in RAID *(meanwhile i'm googling)*

Comment: *(looking through Windows 10 and)* **Based on** [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/72320) saying *"If your disks all say Basic then you either don't have RAID arrays on them or you have hardware RAID."* my SSD says Basic so ..

Comment: Hmmm... kind of a long shot but try to do what I edited in the comment (refresh the site in a few minutes).

Comment: You can refresh the site now.

Comment: [Doesn't seem to change anything :/](https://imgur.com/a/87rcSJz)

Comment: Sorry, but it seems as if the drive is calling it a day. You should ask for your money back :/